# How to generate external intellisense documentation

Tags: documentation, intellisense, xml-documentation, developer-tools

What tool do I need to generate XML intellisense help file as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [XML Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(VS.71).aspx) comments to your code, and then in your Visual Studio project build options ("Build" tab) tick the "XML documentation file" checkbox to extract those comments to the XML file.

Try [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) or [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to help you to create/update the xml documentation comments quickly and easily.